# push notification to ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am building an application that is two parts. web and mobile.
in brief i want to push a notification for the mobile user when a specific thing is received from the server.

for example, if the web user added a task for the mobile user, then: a notification on the mobile appears to inform the mobile user that there is something new in the app. (just like when using facebook)

any one can help me with implementing this?

Note: i configure my application to be apple to receive notifications and it do so.

this is how to push notification from the ios device to itself:

6.3. From the App

You can also send push notifications directly from a mobile application. Remember that you need to have enabled this feature in the Parse app's settings tab by selecting "Yes" under the heading "Client push enabled?". There are several methods that can be called to send push notifications. You can consult the full list in the iOS API documentation. Here is an example:

```
// Create our Installation query
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"deviceType" equalTo:@"ios"];

// Send push notification to query
[PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery 
                           withMessage:@"Hello World!"];
```

any one knows how this can work ?? i can not import these methods !!!

Answer (score 3):

**6 simple steps to delivering push notifications**

```
1. Creating an App ID

2. Generating a Certificate Request

3. Configuring an App ID for Push Notifications

4. Make APNS certificates

5. Upload certificate to Admin panel

6. Create provision profile
```

Also fallow [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) here is good explanation.

Or If you don't have server than you can do this using [iOS Push Notifications Using Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications)

Comment: +1 on the Ray Wenderlich link.  I just posted the same link (and will delete my answer).

Comment: i did all these steps, put how can i push the notification now

Comment: @etab you can do it using your php server.

Comment: mmmm, i got it, just add the script to the server?

Comment: can i send notifications from the app itself ? i saw that in the second link.. can i?

Comment: @etab from the app itself you can't using second link you can :)

Comment: Dear @etab this is only for your testing purpose for brodcost your massage you don't send it from app k .

Comment: ah ok, you mean i can not receive a notification of updates on server unless i use the script on the server. and other techniques is just to insure that the device receive notifications, right ?

Comment: i was thinking about something : why not to receive updates using web service, and then notify the device with it locally. can we ?